# Alert box not show in the right direction when active the condition

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am working on sign up using php. I am just make everything work. Write the data that user name fill up to the mySQUL data. And right now, I am making a condition that user can't create a account that have same username. Everthing is working correctly, however the alert box that show "User name have taken" not show in `login.php` like I want, it's show in `registration.php` and go back after I click ok to turn off like I set it. 
 First I try to copy the code in the `registration.php` top the `login.php` and change `<form action="registration.php" method="post">` to `<form action="login.php" method="post">` the website will not work like I want. 
I just want the alert box show on `login.php` not in `registration.php` 

Here is the code

**registration.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
// header('location:login.php');
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','');

mysqli_select_db($con, 'userregistration');

$name = $_POST['user'];
$pass = $_POST ['password'];
$email = $_POST['mail'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];

$s = " SELECT * FROM usertable WHERE name = '$name'";

$result = mysqli_query($con, $s);

$num = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) >= 1){
    $message="User already taken";
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'> alert('$message');
    window.location.replace(\"login.php\");
    </script>";
}else {
    $reg = "INSERT INTO usertable(name, password, email, phone ) values ('$name', '$pass','$email', '$phone')";
    mysqli_query($con, $reg);
    echo"Registration successfull";
}
?>
```

**login.php**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title> User Login</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mainbody.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="loginheader.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="signinsignup.css">
    <link rel="icon" href="../img/Polar_Bear-512.png">
</head>
<body>
<div class="loginheadercontain">
        <a href="../Index.php"><div class="dotcontain backtohomepage">
            <img src="047_-_homepage-512.png">
        </div></a>
        <div class="backtohomepage">
            <a href="../Index.php">Homepage</a>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

<div class="login-wrap">
    <div class="login-html">
        <div class="containerlogin">
        <div class="avatarcontainer avatar">
            <img src="avatar.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
        <div>
        <input id="tab-1" type="radio" name="tab" class="sign-in" checked>
        <label for="tab-1" class="tab">Sign In</label>
        <input id="tab-2" type="radio" name="tab" class="sign-up">
        <label for="tab-2" class="tab">Sign Up</label>
        <div class="login-form">
            <div class="sign-in-htm">
                <form action="validation.php" method="post">
                <div class="group">
                    <label for="user" class="label">Username</label>
                    <input id="user" type="text" name="user" class="input" placeholder="Enter Your Name" required>
                </div>
                <div class="group">
                    <label for="pass" class="label">Password</label>
                    <input id="pass" name="password" type="password" class="input" data-type="password" placeholder="Enter Your Password" required>
                </div>
                <div class="group">
                    <input type="submit" class="button" value="Sign In">
                </div>
                <div class="hr"></div>
                <div class="foot-lnk">
                    <label for="tab-2">Let's join our community!</a>
                </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        <div class="sign-up-htm">
            <form action="registration.php" method="post">
                <div class="group">
                    <label for="user" class="label">Username</label>
                    <input id="user" type="text" name="user" class="input" placeholder="Enter Your Name" required>
                </div>
                <div class="group">
                    <label for="user" class="label">Password</label>
                    <input id="pass" name="password" type="password" class="input" data-type="password" placeholder="Enter Your Password"required>
                </div>
                <div class="group">
                    <label for="user" class="label">Phone number</label>
                    <input type="tel" name="phone" class="input"placeholder="Enter Your Phone Number">
                </div>
                <div class="group">
                    <label for="user" class="label">Email</label>
                    <input type="email" name="mail" class="input" placeholder="Enter Your Email">
                </div>
                <div class="group">
                    <input type="submit" class="button" value="Sign Up">
                </div>
                <div class="hr"></div>
                <div class="foot-lnk">
                    <label for="tab-1">Already Member?</a>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        </div>    
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code is _wide open_ to SQL injection attacks. Use prepared statements instead of using the user data directly in your database queries.

Comment: Instead of posting to a new page and redirect the user back, which also means that the user will need to reenter the form, you could use [Ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX/Getting_Started). Then you can, using Javascript, post the form in the background without redirecting the client/user at all. Your register.php only needs to return the status of the insert (using, for example, json with potential error or success messages). This makes for a much smoother user experience.

Comment: ^ that and you didn't encrypt the passwords. It's a good practice to already start thinking about security possibilities within your code. It's not a shame to have a secure code nowadays :)

Comment: well, I am just getting new to php, I am just making a demo to study, also I am study network security. So I will leave that problem later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The action value for your sign-up form should be the same login.php file, where you also should move the logic about registering the user.

Or you can move the html in the registration.php (for GET request) and when your request will be POST to run your php code

```
if (isset($_POST)) {
    // run php code from registration.php
} else  {
    ?>
    HTML CODE with your registration form
    <?php
}
```

Comment: Actually, it's better to keep the views and the code separated in different files. Much more structured and easier to maintain.

Comment: Indeed, but in that case he/she need to know how MVC works. Also, using echo in php output should be removed from there :)

Comment: Separating the code and the view isn't MVC on it's own. There are more parts of a MVC structure than that. This is simply separation of concern, which is not a bad thing to learn straight from the start. Also, the OP already has it separated so why move away from it?

Comment: if separated, it's will very hard to maintain in the future